# Dynamic XPath in Selenium - which input field keeps changing

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I tried to find the XPath of a text field *username* and *password*, but it keeps on changing dynamically. I won't be able to use `starts-with` or `contains` in a `findelement` using XPath. Here's the HTML DOM-

```
      <div id="contents">
          <h1 style="white-space:pre; width:80px; float:left;line-height:35px;">Login</h1>
          <span style="float:left; padding-top:13px; COLOR:#990033; font-weight:bold;">  Student | Parent | Faculty</span>
          <div class="form-elements">
          <div class="form-elements">
          <div class="form-elements">
              <div class="label-txt">Password</div>
              <input id="rcnr2uew1m0rkikeaaniwk" type="password" style="display:none;" name="rcnr2uew1m0rkikeaaniwk"/>
              <input id="ko2xs123ebqyoluh15bulu" type="password" style="display:none;" name="ko2xs123ebqyoluh15bulu"/>
              <input id="cuouek4bfz41etm4hroj0r" type="password" style="display:none;" name="cuouek4bfz41etm4hroj0r"/>
              <input id="u2ta3gv2o2ce0azx5plpuh" type="password" name="u2ta3gv2o2ce0azx5plpuh"/>
              <input id="g03nwjuzhqnkuwgsl4q2mu" type="password" style="display:none;" name="g03nwjuzhqnkuwgsl4q2mu"/>
              <input id="gddwv4z3amojk0yvoxi2v4" type="password" style="display:none;" name="gddwv4z3amojk0yvoxi2v4"/>
              <input id="kxecmkho2vf1vcfb42icjr" type="password" style="display:none;" name="kxecmkho2vf1vcfb42icjr"/>
              <span id="ctl04" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">*</span>
         </div>
```

I tried to find the `input[4]` with no style.

Absolute XPath:
 `html/body/form/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input[4]`

Next time how it changes-

Absolute XPath: `html/body/form/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input[17]`

`id` and `name` of the `input` also keeps on changing without any common trait

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the password you could try:

```
//input[@type='password'][not(@style)]
```

For the username :

```
//input[@type='text'][not(@style)]
```

This will select all input elements where the type attribute has the value 'password' (or 'text'), that do not have the style attribute defined.

Ofcourse these are not super precise yet, you could additionally check whether there is a sibling div element that has the value 'Password' or 'User Name'

```
//div[text()='User Name']/../input[@type='text'][not(@style)]
//div[text()='Password']/../input[@type='password'][not(@style)]
```

Comment: Thanks, if _style_ attribute is present then what could be the approach

Comment: Assuming you only want to match input elements that do not have display:none on the style attribute, this should work

    `//div[text()='Password']/../input[@type='password'][not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]`

Answer (score -1):

```
<a class="viewEmailBtn">
 <span class="viewEmailLabel" style="display: none;">SHOW EMAIL ADDRESS</span>
 <span class="viewEmail" style="display: inline;">customer_care@ablerex.com.sg</span>
</a>
```

Code:

```
$company_email = $xpath1->query("//*[@class='viewEmailBtn']/span[2][(contains(@style,'display:none'))]");
```

Comment: I've downvoted your answer as this question already has an accepted answer from almost two years ago so it's not particularly useful.